# Text not displayed in React using Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am fairly new to using react and been following a couple of tutorials on YT, I have ran into a problem with one of them. I copied everything line by line, but my text on 'Home' and 'Login'  doesnt display! I get no errors, but the page remains blank.

here is App.js

```
 import React from 'react'
  import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

  import Login from './components/Login';
  import Home from './container/Home';

  const App = () => {
    return (
     <Routes>
       <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
       <Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
     </Routes>
    );
  };
```

export default App;

Also the index.js file:

```
 import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

   import App from './App';
   import './index.css';

  ReactDOM.render(
     <Router>
         <App />
     </Router>,
      document.getElementById('root'),
 );
```

**Then Login.jsx
**

```
 import React from 'react';

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Login 
    </div>
   
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Finally Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';``your text``

  const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
   Home
      </div>
    );
  };

 export default Home;
```

I know I am missing something, but I cant seem to find it! Any and all help is very much appreciated!

Tried to see if I am using on old version of the BroswerROuter/Routes in React, but I have very little knowledge to see the difference just yet!

Comment: Login.jsx appears to be a duplicate of index.js. Is that correct? I don't see any overt issues with the router/routing, but think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces any issues that we could inspect live?

Comment: yes, I think I copy pasted it twice by accident, ill fix it

Comment: on the code sandbox site funny enough my code seems to be working, the only difference between the two is that I am also using Tailwind in my VS code, dont think that should make a difference though

Comment: I think process of elimination says it *might* just be the Tailwind CSS. When you run locally are either of `Home` or `Login` rendered to the DOM? If you open the browser dev tools and inspect the DOM do you see the components rendered out? If so, what is the CSS currently applied to them?

Comment: they are not rendered at all! I think I must have made a mistake somewhere along the line when I was installing Tailwind! I might just have to restart from the beggining and see if that solves the issue! Thank you for you help anyway! Ill see if that fixes it, if not I shall be back here xD

Comment: Ah, bummer. Yeah, that sounds like good plan.